# python converting strings in list to ints and floats

Tags: python, string, list, int

If I were to have the following list:

```
lst = ['3', '7', 'foo', '2.6', 'bar', '8.9']
```

how would I convert all possible items into either ints or floats accordingly, to get

```
lst = [3, 7, 'foo', 2.6, 'bar', 8.9]
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Loop over each item and make an attempt to convert. If the conversion fail then ignore the item.

Comment: use a foreach, iterate over all items. try convert item to int, catch error then ignore it (or nest another try) then repeat for the whole list. do some research on documentations!

Comment: FWIW, it's generally not a great idea to have a mixture of datatypes in a list. Code to process such lists tends to get messy and require explicit type testing which goes against Python's duck-typing philosophy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Loop over each item and make an attempt to convert. If the conversion fail then you know it's not convertible.

```
def tryconvert(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            return s

lst = ['3', '7', 'foo', '2.6', 'bar', '8.9']
newlst = [tryconvert(i) for i in lst]
print(newlst)
```

Output:

```
[3, 7, 'foo', 2.6, 'bar', 8.9]
```

Comment: This is great, perfect example of [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
lst = ['3', '7', 'foo', '2.6', 'bar', '8.9']

for j,i in enumerate(lst):
    if i.isdigit():
        lst[j]=int(i)
    elif '.' in i:
        lst[j]=float(i)
```

output:

```
[3, 7, 'foo', 2.6, 'bar', 8.9]
```

Comment: This is going to fail if the list contains a string like `'A.B'`