# Convert String into number (Float or int depending upon the variable entered)

Tags: python-3.x

In JavaScript we have +number which converts a string into a number based on its value, as shown below:

`x = '123' => +x returns 123`

`y = '12.3' => +y returns 12.3`

Now if I use int in python it returns:

`x = '123' => int(x) returns 123`

`y = '12.3' => int(y) returns 12 which is wrong as it should return 12.3`

Whereas if I use float:

`x = '123' => float(x) returns 123.0 which is wrong as it should return 123 only though I know 123.0 is same as 123 but I want to parse it to some other query language which identifies the numbers as mentioned above.`

`y = '12.3' => float(y) returns 12.3`

Comment: `int('12.3')` doesn't return `12`... It raises a `ValueError`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python converting strings in list to ints and floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441382/python-converting-strings-in-list-to-ints-and-floats)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int) Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/379966/6045800)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, for some reason you do not want to use `literal_eval`, I want to offer another solution using `regex`. There isn't a necessarily "pretty" built-in method in Python to convert `str` representations of `int` and `float` to `int` and `float` respectively.

```py
import re

def conv(n):
    if isinstance(n, str) and len(n) > 0:
        if re.match(r"^-{0,1}[0-9]+$", n):
            return int(n)
        elif re.match(r"^-{0,1}[0-9]+(\.|e)[0-9]+$", n):
            return float(n)
    return n
```

```py
>>> conv("-123")
-123
>>> conv("123.4")
123.4
>>> conv("2e2")
200.0
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript doesn't have types for integers like other languages (like C) do, so `123` in JS is really `123.0` stored as double but displayed without the decimals. (There's `BigInt` if you want to learn further, but it would have been `123n`).

In Python, you can use [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get the numeric (literal) value from a string representation:

```py
import ast

ast.literal_eval("123")    # -> 123   (int)
ast.literal_eval("123.")   # -> 123.0 (float)
ast.literal_eval("123.0")  # -> 123.0 (float)
```